# finding an explain plan by its hash value

Tags: oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

so when I'm looking at dba_hist_sqlstat data, I see the plan_hash_value of the chosen explain plan. How can I see the explain plan behind this hash value? I haven't been lucky with v$sql_plan or plan_table
or dbms_xplan.display .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to join to [`dba_hist_sql_plan`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3179.htm#REFRN23443) using the `sql_id` and `plan_hash_value`.